# Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having problem with building a game. it keep saying 'Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor'

I followed tips from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588709/error-when-building-project-error-building-player-because-scripts-have-compile) and still got nothing on working.

a friend suggested me to add

```
public static class EditorUtil
```

{

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    //Editr code here
    #endif 
}
```

and it still continues with same error.

this is the full code:

```
 using UnityEngine;

 using System.Collections.Generic;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif



public static class EditorUtil
 {


#if UNITY_EDITOR
    //Editr code here

    static string m_EditorResourcesPath = string.Empty;
    private static string path = string.Empty;

    internal static string editorResourcesPath
    {



        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_EditorResourcesPath))
            {
                string path;

                if (SearchForEditorResourcesPath(out path))
                    m_EditorResourcesPath = path;
                else
                    Debug.LogError("Unable to locate editor resources. Make sure the PostProcessing package has been installed correctly.");
            }

            return m_EditorResourcesPath;
        }
    }

    static bool SearchForEditorResourcesPath(out string path)
    {
        path = string.Empty;

        string searchStr = EditorUtil.path;
        string str = null;

        foreach (var assetPath in AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths())
        {
            if (assetPath.Contains(searchStr))
            {
                str = assetPath;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (str == null)
            return false;

        path = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf(searchStr) + searchStr.Length);
        return true;
    }

    internal static T Load<T>(string path, string name) where T : Object
    {
        EditorUtil.path = path;
        return AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T>(editorResourcesPath + name);
    }

    private static List<string> layers;
    private static string[] layerNames;

    public static LayerMask LayerMaskField(string label, LayerMask selected)
    {
        if (layers == null) 
        {
            layers = new List<string>();
            layerNames = new string[4];
        }
        else 
        {
            layers.Clear ();
        }

        int emptyLayers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        {
            string layerName = LayerMask.LayerToName (i);

            if (layerName != "") 
            { 
                layers.Add (layerName);
            } 
            else
            {
                emptyLayers++;
            }
        }

        if (layerNames.Length != layers.Count)
        {
            layerNames = new string[layers.Count];
        }

        for (int i=0; i < layerNames.Length; i++) 
            layerNames[i] = layers[i];

        selected.value =  EditorGUILayout.MaskField (label, selected.value, layerNames);
        return selected;
    }

    public static Rect GetCurrentRect (float fieldSize = 18)
    {
        return GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(GUIContent.none, GUIStyle.none, GUILayout.Height(fieldSize));
    }

    public static GameObject GetSelectedGameObject ()
    {
        return Selection.activeGameObject;
    }



    public static AnimationClip GetAnimationClipFromAnimator(Animator animator, string name)
    {
        if (animator == null)
            return null;

        foreach (AnimationClip animClip in animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
        {
            if (animClip.name == name)
                return animClip;
        }
        return null;
    }

#endif 
}
```

whats a solution for this? I've searched many posts in here and other forums and yet I keep getting the same error.

[example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsFtG.png)

Edit: [second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAxps.png)

Comment: The actual useful error is the first one. It's saying that the file ended unexpectedly. This means that maybe the compiler was expecting something before the end of the file. Maybe you are missing a closing bracket.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using any function from the `EditorUtil` class anywhere in your script?

Comment: Are you using any namespace?

Comment: @Programmer yes

Comment: I think you should post where you are using/calling the functions from the `EditorUtil` script and I will post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from from your screenshot, you put the script into

Assets/Renegades/Scripts/Utils

However, an Editor script must be put into the Editor folder, not into the Assets folder.

See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html

The UnityEditor Assembly is not accessible to scripts outside the Editor folder. The #if UNITY_EDITOR preprocessor directive does not solve this, because it evaluates to true when the script is run inside the Unity Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Since above script is `using UnityEditor`, either u have to put this script inside folder named **Editor** or you have to use defines `#if UNITY_Editor`. What you have done is also correct but i figured that you might be calling those methods from somewhere, maybe that's why it is still giving compile error. What it does is it will make those methods to exist in Editor only, it won't be there in build. So instead of whole methods, i just used `#if UNITY_EDITOR` for block of code.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections.Generic;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif



public static class EditorUtil
{



    static string m_EditorResourcesPath = string.Empty;
    private static string path = string.Empty;

    internal static string editorResourcesPath {



        get {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (m_EditorResourcesPath)) {
                string path;

                if (SearchForEditorResourcesPath (out path))
                    m_EditorResourcesPath = path;
                else
                    Debug.LogError ("Unable to locate editor resources. Make sure the PostProcessing package has been installed correctly.");
            }

            return m_EditorResourcesPath;
        }
    }

    static bool SearchForEditorResourcesPath (out string path)
    {
        path = string.Empty;

        string searchStr = EditorUtil.path;
        string str = null;
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        foreach (var assetPath in AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths()) {
            if (assetPath.Contains (searchStr)) {
                str = assetPath;
                break;
            }
        }
        #endif
        if (str == null)
            return false;

        path = str.Substring (0, str.LastIndexOf (searchStr) + searchStr.Length);
        return true;
    }

    internal static T Load<T> (string path, string name) where T : Object
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        EditorUtil.path = path;
        return AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<T> (editorResourcesPath + name);
        #else
    return null
        #endif
    }

    private static List<string> layers;
    private static string[] layerNames;

    public static LayerMask LayerMaskField (string label, LayerMask selected)
    {
        if (layers == null) {
            layers = new List<string> ();
            layerNames = new string[4];
        } else {
            layers.Clear ();
        }

        int emptyLayers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            string layerName = LayerMask.LayerToName (i);

            if (layerName != "") { 
                layers.Add (layerName);
            } else {
                emptyLayers++;
            }
        }

        if (layerNames.Length != layers.Count) {
            layerNames = new string[layers.Count];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < layerNames.Length; i++)
            layerNames [i] = layers [i];
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        selected.value = EditorGUILayout.MaskField (label, selected.value, layerNames);
        #endif
        return selected;
    }

    public static Rect GetCurrentRect (float fieldSize = 18)
    {
        return GUILayoutUtility.GetRect (GUIContent.none, GUIStyle.none, GUILayout.Height (fieldSize));
    }

    public static GameObject GetSelectedGameObject ()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        return Selection.activeGameObject;
        #else
    return null
        #endif
    }



    public static AnimationClip GetAnimationClipFromAnimator (Animator animator, string name)
    {
        if (animator == null)
            return null;

        foreach (AnimationClip animClip in animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips) {
            if (animClip.name == name)
                return animClip;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems error is Unexpected 'end-of-file'. That means you are missing curly braces at the end of the script. 
Anyway my solution should work.

Comment: Assets/Renegades/Scripts/Utils/EditorUtil.cs(71,4): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}', expecting `;'

I keep getting this in places

Comment: no still the same. I updated a pic, take a look at it

Comment: Then pls copy my script to any new project and check if it is still giving error or not. Here i'm getting no errors