# Unity does not tell me the files that cause the build error. It only says "Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

I am trying to build an APK in Unity 2019.4.39. Unity says that the build failed, but it does not tell me the files that caused the build to fail.

I can't fix the error because Unity does not tell which files or scripts are bad.

**Can anyone please tell me how to figure out which files caused the build to fail ?**

---

Here are the build errors:

```
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002b3] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:964] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform)
```

---

Here is 1 image of the Unity console with the error message:

[image]

Note: I click on all 3 error messages, but still Unity does not show any filename that causes the build to fail.

---

PS: I know that there is an excellent answer to fix the build error "**Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors**" at this link on StackOverFlow:

[Error when Building Project: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588709/error-when-building-project-error-building-player-because-scripts-have-compile/42588940#42588940)

However, in my case, Unity does not even says which files are bad. So, I can't fix the error if I don't know which files cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

For UnityEditor issues, they don't show up in the console, but they should show up in the log. You could try opening up the log and searching for "error" to diagnose the problem there.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my own issue.  Basically,  the problem is that my project contains 2 versions of **DOTween**, and 2 versions of **Lean**. This causes the build errors.

But, if I only build the scene (without "Play" the scene first), then Unity won't tell me the files or packages that cause the build errors.

I have to "Play" the scene in Unity, and then it will tell me the files or packages that cause that are duplicated, and cause the build error.

---

Here are the details:

To find out what files or packages cause the build errors, I need to "Play" the scene in Unity. When the scene is played in Unity, it tells me that there are 2 conflicting versions of 2 different packages: **DOTween** and **Lean**.

The reason is that my old project already has 1 version of **DOTween** and **Lean**. When I install a new unity package (called **Game_Menu**), it also installs a new version of DOTween and a new version of Lean without deleting or overwriting the old versions. So, there are 2 versions of DOTween, and 2 versions of Lean in my project. This causes the build error.

My solution is to manually remove 1 version of DOTween and 1 version of Lean. Then, Unity builds the APK successfully.

---

In the future, whenever I install this Unity package (called **Game_Menu**), I will need to check to see if my project already contains **DOTween** or **Lean**. If it already does, then I don't need to install these 2 packages.